# Japanese Multiplication: 日本の掛け算

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Is  the Japanese Multiplication really a thing or a joke? How does it work?

[image]

Here is the video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVgnUMdM6ME

Comment: http://www.vedicmaths.org/vertically-and-crosswise and https://www.wikihow.com/Multiply-Using-Vedic-Math

Comment: Why don't you write out how you would compute $21 \times 23$ and see if you can find the numbers $4$, $2$, $6$, and $3$ in your computation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's essentially a visual way to expand the product :
\begin{align}21\times 23 & =(2\times 10+1)\times (2\times 10+3)\\ & =(2\times 2)\times 100 +(2\times3+1\times 2)\times 10+1\times 3\\ & = 4\times 100+8\times 10+3=483.\end{align}

Later in the video you see that with $14$ points, the $1$ is crossed and added to the next number; that's simply reporting the tens to the next power of $10$ like you would report a number in the "usual" way to do written arithmetic.